# How can I set which layers are visible by default in a geoPDF?

Tags: qgis-3, geopdf

I'm using the latest QGIS version 3.10 that has the option to [export to geoPDF](https://north-road.com/2019/09/03/qgis-3-10-loves-geopdf/). Currently the output has all layers visible. I'd like to set which layers are visible by default, so that the user is not overwhelmed with many layers turned on. I know I can do this with [Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109002/can-i-save-an-arcgis-geospatial-pdf-with-layers-turned-off-which-can-then-be-tu) but is it possible to do this directly from QGIS?

Comment: Are the layers visible in PDF also if they have been turned off in the QGIS Project?

Comment: They will only export if they are turned on.